# An alternative way to select multiple columns and fillna() in multiple columns using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, spyder, valueerror

I am trying to select three columns["attacktype1","attacktype2","attacktype3"] whose datatypes are integer from a data frame using pandas and want to fillna(0) into those columns and total those columns into a new column.["Total_attacks"]

The dataset can be downloaded from:
Click [here]https://s3.amazonaws.com/datasetsgun/data/terror.csv

I have tried applying fillna(0) to one column at a time and then totalling them into a new single column.

My first way:

```py
da1 = pd.read_csv('terror.csv', sep = ',', header=0 , encoding='latin' , na_values=['Missing', ' '])
da1.head()
#Handling missing values
da1['attacktype3'] = da1['attacktype3'].fillna(0)
da1['attacktype2'] = da1['attacktype2'].fillna(0)
da1['attacktype1'] = da1['attacktype1'].fillna(0)
da1['total_attacks'] = da1['attacktype3'] + da1['attacktype2'] + da1['attacktype1']

#country_txt is a column which consists of different countries.Want to find "Total_atacks" only for India. Therefore, the condition applied is country_txt=='India'.

a1 = da1.query("country_txt=='India'").agg({'total_attacks':np.sum})
print(a1)
```

My second way(which doesnt work):

```py
da1 = pd.read_csv('terror.csv', sep = ',', header=0 , encoding='latin' , na_values=['Missing', ' '])
da1.head()
#Handling missing values
check1=Df.country_txt=="India"
store=Df[["attacktype1","attacktype2","attacktype3"]].apply(lambda x:x.fillna(0))

Total_attack=Df.loc[check1,store].sum(axis=1)
print(Total_attack)
```

```
I want to apply fillna(0) to multiple columns in a single line and also total those columns in an alternate and effective way.

The error that I get when I use my second way is:

ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then replace missing values by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
check1 = Df.country_txt == "India"
cols = ["attacktype1","attacktype2","attacktype3"]

Df['Total_attack'] = Df.loc[check1, cols].fillna(0).sum(axis=1)
```

For scalar, one number output add `sum`:

```
Total_attack = Df['Total_attack'].sum()
print (Total_attack)
35065.0
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. But the expected output of my first code doesnt match. I want a new column named ''Total Column" which gives me the total number of attacks where all the three coulmns ["attacktype1","attacktype2","attacktype3"] are totalled into one.  Example total number of attacks equals to 35065.

Comment: @Xavier - Edited answer. Assigned output to new column.